# Whats the best way to programatically add a .swf to an asp.net page?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, custom-server-controls

Is there a good way to add a .swf programatically to a panel on an asp.net page - ie: I know i could just insert the html tags:

ie:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="yourflash.swf" width="" height="">
<param name="movie" value="yourflash.swf">
</object>
```

But is there an existing .net or free FLASH component already that you just set the properties on, or do i need to create a custom web control myself (not preferred) so i dont have to continously do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FlashObject.cs`:

```
namespace MyNamespace 
{ 
 using System.Web.UI;

 public class FlashObject : Control
 { public int Width  {get;set}
   public int Height {get;set}
   [UrlProperty] pubic string SourceUrl {get;set;}

   protected override Render(HtmlWriter writer)
    { writer.WriteLine( "<object type='application/x-shockwave-flash' "
                       +" data='{0}' width='{1}' height='{2}'>\r\n"
                       +"    <param name='movie' value='{0}'>\r\n</object>"
                       ,ResolveUrl(SourceUrl)
                       ,Width
                       ,Height);
    }
 }
}
```

`Web.config`:

```
  <system.web> 
     <controls>
       <add tagPrefix="my" namespace="MyNamespace" assembly="MyAssembly" />
     </controls>
  </system.web>
```

`MyPage.aspx`:

```
 <my:FlashObject SourceUrl='~/yourflash.swf' runat='server' />
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like above but instead of emmiting the object and embed code, include swfobject http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/ and emit some nice unintrusive javascript into your page to insert the swf!